# Ruby - recursive each for n-ary tree

Tags: ruby, recursion, tree, each, recursive-descent

Fixed: See EDIT EDIT

I have trouble with writing my own recursive each for an n-ary tree. `@element` is the value of the node, and `@children` is an array of all connected lower nodes. This is my method:

```
def each
  yield(@element)

  @children.each { |x|
    x.each { |i| yield i}
  }
  self
end
```

The problem is that it repeats the lower elements. For example, if I use this to print a node with value o and one child c, it will print 'occ' instead of 'oc'. I really don't know what's going on, so all of my attempted fixes have been ineffective. Any ideas?

EDIT: I think this could be because it's somehow calling each on the node value in addition to yielding it, so when it's a string of a single character it will yield that character then yield it again with a `.each` call.

EDIT EDIT: Thanks for reading, everybody, but I messed up. The problem wasn't in this method, but in another in the same class, to_s. to_s would print correctly, but change the value of the parent node if it was a string. Whenever I tested, I always used to_s first and didn't even realize it. Sorry about this. (Can't let me answer my own question, as I'm a newbie).

Comment: What class is this to be defined on? You should surround your code with a class body.

Comment: You should also describe how `@element` and `@children` are defined on an instance of an n-ary tree.

Comment: The class is omitted because I thought this was the problem area. I'm not really sure anymore.... @element and @children are both passed in to the constructor, @element as any object and @children as an array.

Comment: sawa, asking for the rest of the class did it. I found out my problem. A separate method in this class, to_s, changes the element of the tree, but prints out the correct answer. I always tested with that before using each, so I was sure each was the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Judging from your response, it seems to me that what you want is something like this:

```
class Tree
  def initialize element, children = []
    @element, @children = element, children
  end
  def each &pr
    pr.call(@element)
    @children.each{|x| x.each(&pr)}
    self
  end
end

a = Tree.new('self')
b = Tree.new('parent', [a])
c = Tree.new('grandparent', [b])

c.each{|x| puts x}
# => grandparent
# => parent
# => self

b.each{|x| puts x}
# => parent
# => self
```

One notice is that, since you seem to want to pass the proc object recursively, you should better get that as an argument as `&pr` rather than using `yield`.

Comment: Looks fine, but that bad thing is that you can't use `each` method of a tree object without a block to construct an iterator.